# "Task farming is disabled" or similar socket related problems encountered in IPython.parallel sessions

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, ipython-parallel

IPython.parallel's load balanced interface has been great.  I used it to run complicated scientific computations on a small cluster environment.  Several houndred problems, each taking 5~10 minutes to complete on a PC, were sent to the cluster.  I had no problem getting the results back until I started submitting more strenuous tasks to the cluster.  Some engines were unregistered even though the task assigned completed successfully.  I use "ipcontroller --ping=120000" to circumvent the problem, but IPython now tells me "Task farming is disabled".  What is causing the problem and what should I do?

By the way, I use ssh mode on the cluster.

Comment: Have you used `c.TaskSchedule.scheme_name = 'pure'` in your `ipcontroller_config.py`?

Comment: @minrk: I wonder if this would disable my ability to run tasks on selected engines.  I have both multi-threaded and single-threaded tasks.  All engines are started at the beginning.  A subset of engines, one from each physical node, is selected and used when running the multi-threaded task.

Comment: @minrk: Also, sorry for the late reply.  I was busy amending other parts of my project.